# MediaPlayer and proximity sensor: toggling between speakerphone and earpiece

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, proximitysensor

I'm new to Android! I'm programming a simple Media Player and I want to toggle between speakerphone and earpiece when the audio is playing. I set up a proximity sensor and when the device is close to the ear I want it to play through the earpiece and *vice versa*. At the moment I wrote this code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener{

    TextView proxText;
    SensorManager sm;
    Sensor proxSensor;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    AudioManager am;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
        mp.start();

        am =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        proxSensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
        proxText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.proximityTextView);

        sm.registerListener(this,proxSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.values[0]<event.sensor.getMaximumRange()){
            proxText.setText("close");
            mp.setAudioStreamType(am.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
        }
        else
            proxText.setText("far");
        mp.setAudioStreamType(am.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

but it doesn't work... I think I didn't set up correctly either the MediaPlayer and the AudioManager.

Could you please help me? Thank you in advance! ;-)

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?